# Unable to add webpart to shared version of the page

Tags: configuration

I am trying to add webpart to a page which is shared.
When I go to Site Actions--> Edit Page, it says

> Version: You are editing the Shared Version of this page

When I try to add the webpart the following message is being displayed:

> **Unable to add selected web part(s) The file is not checked out. You must first check out this document before making changes**.

I am using MOSS 2007.

Let me know how to edit a shared version of the page and add the webpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you see a page like that it means it a publishing site, You should sign in and then click on edit. You should now see some controls at the top, You need to select checkout this page. Usually when you edit the page its already checked out ready for editing. Once you have made your changes you would need to check in the changes for others to see and then publish for everyone to see.

for more detailed info on all of this follow this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-pages-in-a-publishing-site-HA010099663.aspx#BM2

**EDIT**

you need to do the following:

go to the Pages Library -> Settings -> Document Library settings -> Versioning Settings -> Enable the versioning. Now go back to the page and you should be able to add your webpart :)

hope it helps :)

Comment: I am signed in as admin and clicked on Edit page. The only option that comes is Version: You are editing the Shared Version of this page. There is no Edit bar. I believe since the page is shared with others I am unable to edit

Comment: it might be that someone else has checked out this page

Comment: you need to do the following: Navigate to the Pages Library - Settings - Document Library settings - Versioning Settings - Enable the versioning. Now go back to the page and you should be able to add your webpart :)

Comment: I am sure and verified that no one has checked out the page. The versioning is already enabled in the Document library settings

Comment: maybe this can help? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminlegacy/thread/53b591eb-1cec-45bb-a7f9-a9d4bd5e6e93

Comment: Ok, just to make sure. can you do the following, goto the page - then siteactions - site settings - modify all site settings - under site administration click on site libraries and lists - click on customize "pages". where you can see web address copy that url and past it in a new tab in the browser. You can now 100% see who its checkout if atall. Let me know the result ;)